# minimum bottleneck path from s to t with 1 =<w(v) =< |V|

Tags: algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search

given a directed graph G(V,E) with weights , all weights have the value of 1 to |V| , given two vertices s and t find minimum bottleneck path from s to t in linear time .

my idea is to add edges gradualy according to its weights first add edges with weight equal to 1 if there is a path from s to t return 1 as the min bottleneck else add all edges with weight 2 and according to the edge itself change the visited vertices to unvisited .

i am not sure if the solution above is linear . any ideas ? thank you

Comment: Your solution will process each edge only once. So it will be linear with respect to the edges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Because all the weights are in [1,|V|], you can sort the edges by weight in linear time.
2. Then, clear all edges from the graph and start adding them back in weight order, stopping when vertex *t* becomes reachable from vertex *s*.
3. At this point, the graph will include a minimum bottleneck path, and no edges will be more expensive that the bottleneck.  You can do a BFS in this graph to find the path.

In order to make this a linear time algorithm, you need to do step (2) in linear time, and for that you need to track which vertices are reachable from *s* in amortized constant time per edge.  The trick is to process each edge for reachability just once:

- When you add an edge from a reachable vertex, its target becomes reachable immediately.
- Otherwise, it goes into a queue for that vertex, and all the edges in that queue will be processed when their source becomes reachable, making all of their targets reachable at the same time.